# Schedule the import of excel data to oracle database table?

Tags: excel, oracle, import

I have a excel file which keeps updating in 15 minutes.

I want to store all the excel data to oracle database automatically. I mean when ever new rows insert into excel file it must insert into oracle database immediately. If any duplicate rows added to excel file it should not be inserted into database.

Comment: is this real excel file? I mean, the binary one. If yes I guess you need to stick to some Excel macros and database connection right from there. But if this is an old one, so you can open it in notepad++and extract the data from there I would go with a script (unix or windows, not sure what you're using) to go with SQL*Loader to a stage table (but cleaning it up before) and then run a procedure (which you will write =) ) which will get the differences, duplicates and do the proper stuff about it. Makes sense? You can run the script to check for modif date every minute and then start process

Comment: Please provide code you already have.

Comment: Its a exported excel file from MS SQL Server 2012 and keeps inserting new rows as db inserting new records.

Comment: you could give it a try and check if you're able to get the contents in a text form when you open it via notepad? if this is a text file and not the binary, we can talk about my solution. Is the SQL Server which writes to the file? It adds rows or recreates the whole file?